# Can I buy a plug adapter in Frankfurt airport?

Tags: usa, airports, electronic-items, shopping, fra

I'm going to travel from EU to US in a week and I need a plug adapter to charge my phone. But I'm having trouble finding a store that sells US to EU adapters in the city where I live (Riga).

I'm going to have a 2 hour layover in Frankfurt so I'm hoping to purchase an adapter during that time. Are there any stores in the secure area of Frankfurt airport that sell plug adapters? If so, how do I find one?

Note that I don't need to convert frequency or voltage (most phone chargers support 50-60 Hz and 110-220 V).
This is the kind of adapter I'm looking for:

[image: The adapter that I'm looking for]

Comment: Not an answer to your question about Frankfurt airport, but [this](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g274967-i1134-k9032503-Urgent_where_to_buy_travel_adapters-Riga_Riga_Region.html) tripadvisor topic suggests two shops at two malls in your city that should have them. Make sure you know what kind of adapter you need (usually just a plug adapter these days- if your device can accept 120VAC US power directly). If it's something like a hair dryer, it's probably not economical to adapt it.

Comment: That topic is about EU to UK adapters, which are indeed available in the shops where I've looked. I'm guessing there just isn't much demand for US to EU adapters in Riga.

Comment: @JoErNanO I'm sorry, how is this a price-shopping question? I'm only asking about the availability of a generic item relevant only to travelers.

Comment: I'm thinking it falls in the "availability change frequently in many locations" category. I might be wrong though, so do not hesitate to edit and vote to reopen.

Comment: I think the availability of plug adapters is unlikely to change frequently. I've edited the question, but I don't see a "vote to reopen" button.

Comment: "US to EU" adapter doesn't make a lot of sense in the first place, since the various member countries of the EU use a number of _different_ plugs.

Comment: @HenningMakholm most of the EU uses the same plug. Feel free to suggest a less ambiguous term though.

Comment: @Nikolai: I have no way of knowing which of the _several diffferent_ plugs used around the EU you mean. Feel free to amend your question with a picture of the plug you mistakenly believe is used everywhere in the EU.

Comment: @HenningMakholm if it wasn't already obvious, I'm aware that a few EU countries use a different plug, and I mean the plug that's used in most of the EU.

Comment: I've voted to reopen your question, but please add that the the frequency in Latvia (50 Hz) differs from the frequency in the United States (60 Hz) and that you need a voltage converter which also changes the frequency, which are hard to find.

Comment: @Dorothy I've added a note explaining why I don't need one.

Comment: Good; also consider waiting until you arrive, or ordering right now [on Amazon in the US](https://www.amazon.com/ANRANK-Adapter-Socket-Adaptor-Converter/dp/B01M6188NP/ref=pd_lpo_vtph_23_tr_t_3?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=67NQV6788HYZB69CB6AP) and having it sent to the address you'll go to on arrival... it's ridiculously inexpensive here

Comment: @Dorothy the Amazon suggestion is a good one, but trying to find an adapter after arriving in the US is in my experience unlikely to succeed.  In my experience, one can readily find adapters targeted towards a place's residents as they prepare to travel abroad, not visitors who have arrived from abroad.  It's therefore relatively easy in the US to find adapters that allow you to plug US electronics into foreign sockets, but difficult to find those that allow plugging foreign electronics into US sockets.

Comment: @phoog totally agree; where I more easily find them in the US, btw, is uni shops that have lots on foreign students

Comment: Not about the airport, but I know the adapters used to be available at Elkor Plaza, and also Euronics at Galerija Rīga. They're a bit difficult to find online, probably in part due to nobody being able to agree what they are called in Latvian, but they are available at the bigger electronics stores.

Comment: @Nikolai: Different plug _from what_? I have personal knowledge that the UK, Denmark, Germany, France, and Italy use 5 different plug standards. By no reasonable standard is any of these 5 used in "most of the EU", and it is doubtful if there is any "most of the EU" _left_ if you exclude those.

Comment: (It is possible to create _non-earthed_ male plugs that will fit in 4 of the 5 types of sockets I list, though -- perhaps that is what you mean)?

Comment: @DUman neither Elkor Plaza nor Euronics had it. I ended up just borrowing one at the hotel desk. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been in Frankfurt on a connection, and yes, there is an electric store there, it called [Pax Electronics](http://www.pax-airport-shopping.com/index.html).

Yes, it's quite expensive, but they do have such adapters. I've been in PhotAir one, near the Z-gates. You canfind a map [here](https://shop.frankfurt-airport.com/en/service/photair).

Also, such adapters can be found in JFK or other big airports in USA, they have a lot of variants, from $4 (simple) to $20 (multi-format) ones, for example:

[image]

Comment: "Yes, it's quite expensive" approximately what kind of price range should I expect?

Comment: I think that `30 EUROs` is a reality here. Maybe you can contact them and find out.

Comment: I contacted them, here's their response: "Yes we have the Adapter, the Price is 14,99 EUR, you can worldwide plugs inside."

Comment: You probably should answer your own question

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you can. You can search for electronic shops in the airport here
https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/shop---dine/exclusive-offers.overview.map.html#map/category=einkaufen/subCategory=technik-and-entertainment/page=1 (check all levels)

There are plenty of shops past security (airside). Keep in mind that FRA is big. It has two Terminals each with multiple gate areas: Terminal 1 has A, B, C & Z, Terminal 2 has D & E). I'm not sure whether there is an airside connection between the terminals (there is a mono rail train) and area Z is more isolated since it has all the US flights. SO you want to search for a store in your departure gate area.

However, it will be VERY expensive. I would budget for at least 30 Euros. I would recommend to order something online if you can. For example I use a lot of these electronics and chargers [https://www.amazon.com/Ckitze-Flat-Europe-Asia-Adapter/dp/B002TZBW74](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002TZBW74) . I order a dozen and through a handful in my travel bag. The tend to get lost easily !

Comment: Could you name some of the shops from that list that are likely to have plug adapters?